# Maven2 vs Maven3 metadata.xml

Tags: maven

I am getting two different version of metadata.xml while I am using maven2 ( 2.0.9) for both projects. One is looks more like maven3 kind of metadata.xml but I never used maven3 in my project.

1.34-SNAPSHOT

```
<metadata><groupId>com.dtsoft</groupId><artifactId>XXX</artifactId><version>1.34-SNAPSHOT</version><versioning><snapshot><timestamp>20150510.120016</timestamp><buildNumber>61</buildNumber></snapshot><lastUpdated>20150510120016</lastUpdated></versioning></metadata>
```

1.35-SNAPSHOT

```
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0"><groupId>com.dtsoft</groupId><artifactId>XXX</artifactId><version>1.35-SNAPSHOT</version><versioning><snapshot><timestamp>20150316.085852</timestamp><buildNumber>10</buildNumber></snapshot><lastUpdated>20150321103809</lastUpdated><snapshotVersions><snapshotVersion><classifier>sources</classifier><extension>jar</extension><value>1.35-20150316.085852-10</value><updated>20150316085852</updated></snapshotVersion><snapshotVersion><extension>jar</extension><value>1.35-20150316.085852-10</value><updated>20150316085852</updated></snapshotVersion><snapshotVersion><extension>pom</extension><value>1.35-20150316.085852-10</value><updated>20150316085852</updated></snapshotVersion></snapshotVersions></versioning></metadata>
```

Can anyone tell why I am getting two different versions ?

Thanks

Comment: Really using Maven 2.0.9? If so [stop using it immediatly](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html). Migrate asap to Maven 3.X...

Comment: I will stop using 2.0.9. But right now we are using in our project and I need to find out why maven-metadata.xml is different for snapshot (trunk) vs release project while maven is same. Please suggest.

Comment: Are you looking in your local repository if yes? Just delete it completely and start working with Maven 3.

Comment: No. I am looking at my remote nexus repository hosted on unix server.

Comment: Than ignore it completely. cause the uniqueVersion property in settings.xml is the culprit which should be changed or just ignore it and is ignored in settings.xml in Maven 3.

Comment: There is no property name uniqueVersion in settings.xml. Here is a snapshot of it.

Comment: <repository>
                    <id>Repo1 Maven</id>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
                    <releases>
                      <enabled>true</enabled>
                      <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                 </repository>

Comment: Could you please tell how maven-metadata.xml file got generated as I deleted this file and it got generated again with same contents as before.

Comment: I am getting this error while compiling my project. This error suddently start coming up. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolutionException: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-
api_1.0_spec:jar': Cannot find parent: org.apache.geronimo.genesis.config:config for project: null:project-config:pom:1.1 for project null:project-config:pom:1.1
  org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1